# Jquery ui dialog causing problems with embedded script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i have a problem using jqueryUI dialog
when i include a `<script>` tag inside a div and use `.dialog()` in that div, the javascript gets executed twice.

as far as i understand this is because the dialog encloses my div into another div, causing the browser to parse again the inside html.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/u7Pfd/)

unfortunately i cannot remove the script tag from the div.
i cant figure out how to solve this besides using a flag to mark if my js has been executed or no but it cant be the only solution.

anyone knows a better way to fix this?

Comment: I understand you can't remove the script from the div tag, but can you change it?

Comment: Which execution would you rather have? The first or the second? :)

Comment: yes, i can change it.
the two executions are from the same code, i just want it to run once